How to have the update info form already filled with the user informations when he logs in?
I have a local storage where the users are saved. After they login i have a part in the page where they have to update their infos. How to have the form already filled with their info after they login?
I have this function and i do not know where to go from here:
function populateForm() {

  let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData')) || [];
  if (userData) {

      document.getElementById('firstName').value = userData.firstName;
      document.getElementById('lastName').value = userData.lastName;
      document.getElementById('username').value = userData.username;
      document.getElementById('birthDate').value = userData.birthDate;
      document.getElementById('email').value = userData.email;
  }

}

What happens when you execute this function?

"I have this function and i do not know where to go from here" - Have you tested your function?  Is something specific not working as expected?  It's not clear to me what problem you have encountered.  Though at a glance you seem to be unsure whether your data is an object or an array.  We can't see your data so we don't know.

i have this error in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')
at populateForm

@MarianPricope: Then at least one of the elements you're looking for with getElementById wasn't found.  The line of code which produces the error is indicating which one.  We can't see your HTML so we don't know.

you were right. 2 of them were written diferent in HTML... it`s good to have a fresh mind see the problem. Thank a lot :D
